# Excel - named range in a conditional formatting formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, named-ranges

TLDR; seems like CF thinks my formula with named range is an array, and I want it to function like a flat formula.

Long time lurker, first time poster!

I have been creating nice elaborate conditional formatting formulas for a while now. However, I have always had a challenge when using these with named ranges. The formulas work great when in a cell, but when placed into CF, they fail.

Perhaps my issue is related to the way in which CF seems to already identify these formulas as arrays. Perhaps somebody can help me understand how best to overcome this issue. I'll link a document for illustration.

So when I place escalating numbers in A1:J1, and place in A2:J2 this formula

```
=IF(TheNums>4,TRUE,FALSE)
```

then E2:J2 all come back TRUE. Placing the same formula into CF comes back all FALSE. If I enter the same formula as an array with CSE, I get FALSE all across.

Can somebody help with my syntax to hopefully stop this from failing?

Thanks so much!
Kyle

[[linked here]](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ie4eeog6i3pgnw/POC.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: I should say, I totally understand that my simple request above could possibly be done with direct references. This is how I've gotten around the situation in the past. However, my current task is a bit more complicated than usual, and I'd love to use named ranges for readability.

Comment: Updated link with a new file. I'm afraid the simple situation I presented lacked fullest conveyance of the issue I have at hand. I will be using CF in a 2 dimensional grid to highlight true/false. I've recreated a simple version of these grids to expose the challenge that I have. I want to used named ranges in my CF formula and expect it to evaluate the cell above and the cell to the right... rather than consider the named cell range in the entirety as part of an array. My final product won't have true/false in the cells, so I can't use that as a trigger. I'd just like CF to not be in array.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you may need is to change the way the named range works. For example, if your named range returns more than one cell, the Conditional Formatting won't be able to handle it very easily (you would probably have to create a UDF in VBA). However, there might be a quicker/easier solution.

If your named range is this:

```
=Sheet1!$A$1:$J$1
```

Change it to/add another one:

```
=Sheet1!A$1
```

Make sure that you have the correct cell selected when you define a named range without an absolute reference. In this case you would need to select any cell in column A because the column reference is relative, not absolute. Now will you get a single cell reference back from the named range. It will always be a cell on row 1. This will make it easier for you do something with it in Conditional Formatting.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this method will help you to apply Conditional Formatting for the Row:**

**Note:**

- *This solution is based on the attached Drop 
  Box image.*
- **This solution will work on single Row data 
  only.**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Enter this Formula in Cell `A2`, fill it Right.

`=IF(Mydata1>4,TRUE, FALSE)`

**N.B.**

- Now, to convert the formula into Array (CSE), select `A2:G2`, then Press `F2` & finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.
- You find `A2:G2` is now filled with below shown array formula.

  `{=IF(Mydata1>4,TRUE,FALSE)}`

  - `Mydata1` is Named Range (`A1:G1`).
  - Select both Rows (`A1:G2`), reach to
    `Conditional Formatting`, `New Rule`.
  - Apply this Formula.`=A2=TRUE` & an appropriate 
    Color Format, finish with `Ok`.

Comment: Good try, Rajesh. Unfortunately, I think the simple exercise I presented probably confused you about the point I was needing clarified. And perhaps it isn't possible at all. Array formulas will fail at the comparison I'm attempting to do in CF, so I've added to my spreadsheet in hopes of further proving the issue. I need the CF to look at the cell range above and cell range to the right to do comparison... but if I name the ranges, I can't use the named range because CF thinks I want to include the entire range in every cell's calculation, rather than just 1 above and 1 right cells.

Comment: Hi @KyleBecker,, unfortunately you landed with wrong pick (*Array in cell shows why*),, now please read the `N.B`. part I've edited, **shows how to fill entire range A2:G2 with an Array formula**,, just follow instruction and U find is working !!